# Lifetime errors I don't know how to solve

Tags: rust

Hi I am having issues with lifetimes in a fairly simple test case
and I can't seem to understand what the compiler is telling me.
The code below pastes into Rust playground.

The idea about the code is that `Element`s are strung together into a pipeline. Data eventually will be pass one one element to the next. Each stage has a `(rx, tx)` pair on which it receives input from previous stage and sends data to next stage. I can mark the `Element`s as `Sync` as only one `Element` will ever process one part of the data at one time.

The errors are:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
  --> <anon>:56:18
   |
56 |         for e in self.elements {
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the lifetime 'a as defined on the body at 53:53...
  --> <anon>:53:54
   |
53 |     pub fn run(&self) -> Vec<thread::JoinHandle<()>> {
   |                                                      ^
note: ...so that expression is assignable (expected std::vec::Vec<Box<&Element>>, found std::vec::Vec<Box<&'a Element + 'a>>)
  --> <anon>:56:18
   |
56 |         for e in self.elements {
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
note: ...so that the type `[closure@<anon>:62:41: 64:15 e:Box<&Element>, sender:std::sync::Arc<std::sync::Mutex<std::sync::mpsc::SyncSender<(std::string::String, std::string::String)>>>, receiver:std::sync::Arc<std::sync::Mutex<std::sync::mpsc::Receiver<(std::string::String, std::string::String)>>>]` will meet its required lifetime bounds
  --> <anon>:62:27
   |
62 |              handles.push(thread::spawn(move || {
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The first error I am confused by as `Element`s are defined as
`&'a Element` so should they not tell the compiler that they stick around
for along as `Pipeline`?

The second error I guess is telling me `Vec<thread::JoinHandle<()>>` as to be told it depends on the lifetime `'a` ? I am not sure how to convey that though.

I hope the third will make more sense after I correct the first two. At the moment I just don't know what its telling me.

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread;
use std::result::Result;
use std::sync::mpsc::{SyncSender, Receiver, sync_channel};

pub trait Element: Send + Sync {
    fn run(&self, output: Arc<Mutex<SyncSender<i32>>>,
                   input: Arc<Mutex<Receiver<i32>>>);
}

pub struct TestElement {}

impl TestElement {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        TestElement {}
    }
}

impl Element for TestElement {
    fn run(&self, output: Arc<Mutex<SyncSender<i32>>>,
                   input: Arc<Mutex<Receiver<i32>>>) {
        println!("Hello");
    }
}

pub struct Pipeline<'a> {
    elements: Vec<Box<&'a Element>>,
}

impl<'a> Pipeline<'a> {
    pub fn new(name: String) -> Self {
        Pipeline {
            elements: Vec::new(),
        }
    }

    pub fn run(&self) -> Vec<thread::JoinHandle<()>> {
        let mut handles = Vec::with_capacity(self.elements.len());

        for e in self.elements {
             let channel = sync_channel::<i32>(1000);
             let sender = Arc::new(Mutex::new(channel.0)).clone();
             let receiver = Arc::new(Mutex::new(channel.1)).clone();

             handles.push(thread::spawn(move || {
                 e.run(sender, receiver);
             }));
        }

        handles
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut test_element = TestElement::new();
    let mut pipeline = Pipeline::new("example pipeline".to_string());

    let handles = pipeline.run();
}
```

Comment: Could you further simplify your code? It's still quite a big chunk of code and it's easier to answer and easier for you to understand when we're only dealing with a small piece of code. Thanks :)

Comment: I tried to reduce the size a little. I could reduce more but that would remove some of the errors and I wasn't sure whether I should as I don't know if they are separate errors or all related to one fix. What do you think ?

Comment: Why are you using `Box<&'a Element>`? `Box` already heap allocates and is basically just a pointer, thus `Box<Element>` should be sufficient. This would also solve your lifetime problem (but shine light on other problems). Also note, that a spawned thread can outlive everything else, so the threads spawned in `Pipeline::run()` can live longer than the `Pipeline` object! This is not an answer, but a nudge into the right direction, I hope.

Comment: I was using Box here as without I get errors about not knowing the size of Element as it is a trait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `note` reported by the compiler *adds context* to the preceding error or warning. It's not a separate error; fixing the error will make the notes go away.

Now unfortunately, the error message isn't all that clear. The problem is that you're trying to move `e`, which is of type `Box<&'a Element>`, into the closure passed to `thread::spawn`, but `thread::spawn` requires a closure that is valid for the `'static` lifetime; i.e. it doesn't contain references that are shorter than `'static` (and `'static` is the longest lifetime available: it corresponds to the duration of the whole program). `'a` is not guaranteed to be equal to `'static`, hence the error.

Your code is invalid because the thread may continue running after the `Element` the reference is referring to has been freed.

One possible solution is to simply not use references inside the `elements` vector: use `Vec<Box<Element>>`. That only works if you don't need to reuse the elements afterwards, though.

Another option is to use thread-safe reference counters ([`Arc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html)) instead of simple references. This eliminates lifetime concerns, but introduces a bit of runtime overhead.

One last option is to use [`crossbeam`](https://aturon.github.io/crossbeam-doc/crossbeam/) to [spawn](https://aturon.github.io/crossbeam-doc/crossbeam/struct.Scope.html#method.spawn) [scoped](https://aturon.github.io/crossbeam-doc/crossbeam/fn.scope.html) threads. With this option, you can continue using references. One thing you can't do with this is return the join handles before the scope has ended. You could still return the join handles from `Pipeline::run`, but `crossbeam` will join all the threads before `scope` returns.

*Historical note: Just before Rust reached 1.0, there used to be an implementation of scoped threads in the standard library. But instead of using a closure for the scope, it would simply return a `JoinHandle`, and the safety of this implementation relied on the program calling the destructor on the `JoinHandle`. If the destructor wasn't run at the appropriate time (e.g. you called `mem::forget`), then the thread would keep running and potentially reference deallocated objects. `crossbeam` still relies on the destructor being called, but it's written so that users of the library can never obtain ownership of the `Scope`, so the library can guarantee that the destructor will be run.*

Comment: Thanks in the end I used crossbeam. The multiple errors were confusing me.

Shame they can't reintroduce crossbeam into the standard library.

Comment: They certainly could introduce `crossbeam`'s functionality in the standard library, but developing new features as an external library has several advantages. It gives the authors more flexibility to change the API in the early days and it gives them more audience, as new features introduced in the standard library are first introduced as _unstable_, which means only those who use a nightly compiler can use them.